# What is the significance of the saddle point?

Tags: calculus

In machine learning for example, local/global minimums/maximums are important as the indicate the validity and accuracy of the function.

Does the saddle point have such significance in other applications or is it used in any advanced mathematics for any important proofs?

Comment: Yes. Yes it is. I think of it as something to be aware of. In higher dimensions it is like a local extrema--funny things can happen there that you sometimes have to watch out for it. Or at least check it along with maxima/minima